# Mobile app database access

Tags: android, database, mobile

I have been asked to write a mobile android app to interface with a website. When pulling content from the site, I don't think scraping the site would be very efficient. I would like to interface with the database. Think of the scenario as facebook mobile app interfacing with the facebook databases that fuel facebook.com (so there's a mobile app, a web app, and a database in this equation). Would I just create a db account for the mobile app and then every phone using that app would use the same database account (This sounds like a terrible idea imo)? The user will be asked to authenticate in the app before they can start getting information from the it.

Comment: You may want to give more information, such as what type of data would the mobile app be getting.

Comment: user A logs into the mobile app and has access to personal information, contacts, some number of text messages.  My buddy suggested that it should be hitting an API, but I **really** don't want to go through the effort of writing an API if I don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

In general you don't want to be accessing the database directly via the phone (if that is even possible). The more standard way with mobile clients is to build a set of RESTful APIs that you can invoke via normal HTTP GETs and POSTs. These will present the data in a more lightweight (JSON, XML) way to the app, so that the "decoding" effort is reduced. Authentication is done via standard HTTP AUTH. That's the short version.